# How to enable Google Translate in WebView Android App

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am working on a website to simply convert it into the android app using a WebView. The website has Google Translation and I want to achieve this functionality in the android WebView app.

I have searched a lot about this but did not find a proper solution. I have enabled JavaScript, below is the code:

```
binding.tland.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
binding.tland.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
binding.tland.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
binding.tland.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
binding.tland.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

The Google Chrome App is doing what exactly I want.

[image: Desktop Google Chrome Screenshot]

[image: Android Google Chrom Screenshot]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No brother, this feature is only available in Chrome.

Comment: yes, it work in Chrome but not in WebView

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use Google custom Chome tab instead of WebView when you want to have the same Google Translate feature for specific web url.

The tutorial is here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/integration-guide/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: May I know how you added google translate to your website? am trying to do that

Comment: this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp